# How do I append a value to an array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

For a numerical analysis class I need to make a for loop that must do a couple of things:

1. Make a certain 'Dt' (a time step that gets smaller and smaller) and add this to an array called Dt_list. This must be an array containing all the different Dt's at the end of the loop
2. Call a function called "EstimateError" with multiple parameters including Dt which changes every time the loop restarts. This function returns a one dimensional array with two components: ([est_global_error_1, est_global_error_2])
   This output has to also be added to an array called: err_list being a two dimensional array.
3. inside the for loop there must be a (nested) 'if' that checks whether or not one of the values in the global_trunction_error is smaller than or equal to 0.001, if this is the case the for loop must break.

Although seemingly easy, I can not get it to work properly after trying many variations. There seems to be something going wrong when I try to append a value to either one of the lists.

After the for-loop I must attain an optimal Dt which should be the last value on the Dt_list.

```
err_list = np.array([],[])
Dt_list = np.array([])


for i in np.linspace(0,100,101):
    Dt = (0.25)*(0.5)**(i)
    
    global_trunction_error = EstimateError(t_0,t_end,Dt,y_0, a,c,A,C,W_0)
    np.append(err_list, global_trunction_error)
    
    Dt_list = np.append(Dt_list, Dt)
    
    if (abs(global_trunction_error[0])) <= 0.001:
        if (abs(global_trunction_error[1])) <= 0.001:
            break

            
Dt_opt = Dt_list[-1]
```

Comment: What does the `EstimateError` function look like? If it accepts arrays (give it a try), then you don't need this loop. You can nearly always avoid loops with NumPy. Then you can deal with the conditional using NumPy's indexing.

Comment: you are absolutely correct! however this particular assignment requires me to seperate the functions EstimateError, and this for-loop is actually also a function. This is how the teacher wants us to do it unfortunately...

Comment: OK, but maybe that function already deals with arrays? Did you try it? Or can you show it? NumPy is not really designed to work in loops like this.

Comment: I have no idea what is your problem. And I don't know what you means `"something going wrong"`. And we can't run code to see problem, and we can't read in your mind. You have to describe all details in question (not in comment). If you get wrong results then show what you get and what you expected. Better create minimal working code with example data and show expected result - so we could run it and see problem.

Comment: `np.array([],[])` is wrong.  Stick with lists, `x=[]` and list append.  Do not try to use `np.append` ,

Answer (score 1):

Your code starts off wrong:

```
In [199]: err_list = np.array([],[])    
In [200]: err_list
Out[200]: array([], dtype=[])
```

I expected this to raise an error, since the 2nd argument to `np.array` is supposed to be a `dtype`.  Initially I was puzzled by that `dtype=[]`, but then realized is a compound dtype with 0 fields.  Normally a compound dtype looks like `[('f0',float),('f1',int)]`, so I've never seen a 0 field dtype before.

Secondly you probably got an error like this:

```
In [204]: np.append(err_list, (1,2))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [204], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 np.append(err_list, (1,2))

File <__array_function__ internals>:5, in append(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:4817, in append(arr, values, axis)
   4815     values = ravel(values)
   4816     axis = arr.ndim-1
-> 4817 return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)

File <__array_function__ internals>:5, in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: The DTypes <class 'numpy.dtype[int32]'> and <class 'numpy.dtype[void]'> do not have a common DType. For example they cannot be stored in a single array unless the dtype is `object`.
```

**I probably should have just voted to close this question since you didn't provide any errors or their tracebacks.**

First, `np.append` is not a list append clone!  It returns a value; it does not change an array in-place.

Second, `concatenating` with a structured array requires arguments with a matching dtype.

On second thought, I am going to vote to close.  Go back to your code and rewrite using lists and list appends.  Appending values to arrays is error prone and inefficient.

Comment: My apologies for the vagueness, but I am not allowed to share more code than this...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for responding!

I found a way around my problem, I just divided the two dimensional array into two seperate lists and then combined them later on.

```
err_list_1 = []
err_list_2 = []
Dt_list = []


for i in np.linspace(1,100,10):
    Dt = (0.25)*(0.5)**(i)
    
    global_trunction_error = EstimateError(t_0,t_end,Dt,y_0, a,c,A,C,W_0)
    err_list_1.append(global_trunction_error[0])
    err_list_2.append(global_trunction_error[1])
    
    Dt_list.append(Dt)
    
    if (abs(global_trunction_error[0])) <= 0.001:
        if (abs(global_trunction_error[1])) <= 0.001:
            break

            
Dt_opt = Dt_list[-1]
err_list = np.array((err_list_1, err_list_2))

Dt_list = np.array((Dt_list))
```